# How i can read website, add values in two input (username and password) and submit form in code behind

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, httpwebresponse

I use the WebRequest class to read the site, after this, I have a string variable que stores all site content.
At this point, I add two values in two inputs.
After adding These two values, how do I give to submit the form?

My code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

string retorno = reader.ReadToEnd();

retorno = retorno.Replace("<input id=\"username\"", "<input id=\"username\" value=\"agora@myemail.com\" ").Replace("<input id=\"password\"", "<input id=\"password\" value=\"xxxxx\" ");
```

Comment: There is no need to get the site content. Just mimick the form and http post it to server.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- First make HTTP GET request to have Cookies/Session values from
  Response object which will be used in further request.
- Make HTTP POST (with attached cookie/session values if any from
  previous steps) request to website with input values as content.
  username='xxxx'&password='zzzzzzzzzz'
- Use Fiddler/DeveloperTools to see what's going
  on(Headers/Cookies/Session/Form data) when you browser and submit in 
  browser and replicate samethings in C# using WebRequest/WebClient